# Vim not recognising username when trying to open a file over FTP (Mac OS X)

Tags: vim, ftp

I'm trying to edit some files on a remote server with Vim. I've managed this on other servers without trouble in the past, but in this case when I type:

`$ vim ftp://username@xxxxxx.com/`

I'm prompted for a password, I type it in and I see this:

```
Name (notixvalet.com:george): User cannot log in. 
Please login with USER and PASS. 
Please login with USER and PASS. 
Please login with USER and PASS. 
ftp: Login failed
```

'george' is my username on my local machine (Mac OS X 10.8.) Vim seems to be ignoring the username I give it and trying to log on as 'george', no matter what I do. To test this I created a new account on my MacBook with the same username as the username on the server I'm trying to log in as, then from that account I can log in fine. This is obviously a VERY hacky solution - how can I connect using the right username from my regular account?

(Incidentally, the username and password I'm using are 100% definitely right - I can use them to connect to the server through an FTP client such as FileZilla.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't simply use your FTP client to connect to and browse the server and MacVim to edit?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker. Email the author of the responsible _netrw plugin_ (Charles Campbell); his address can be found in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are using to edit the remote files is `netrw`, as noted by Ingo in the comments. You can read the plugin help file through `:h netrw`. In special:

```
  NETRC                         *netrw-netrc*

  The <.netrc> file, typically located in your home directory, contains lines
  therein which map a hostname (machine name) to the user id and password you
  prefer to use with it.

  The typical syntax for lines in a <.netrc> file is given as shown below.
  Ftp under Unix usually supports <.netrc>; ftp under Windows usually doesn't.
  >
     machine {full machine name} login {user-id} password "{password}"
     default login {user-id} password "{password}"

  Your ftp client must handle the use of <.netrc> on its own, but if the
  <.netrc> file exists, an ftp transfer will not ask for the user-id or
  password.

     Note:
     Since this file contains passwords, make very sure nobody else can
     read this file!  Most programs will refuse to use a .netrc that is
     readable for others.  Don't forget that the system administrator can
     still read the file!  Ie. for Linux/Unix: chmod 600 .netrc
```

Is there any chance that you forgot to copy the ~/.netrc file from the other servers where you can connect without problems? Or it has incorrect permissions, as mentioned on the last paragraph?

Comment: D'oh! Editing ~/.netrc file seems to have fixed it. In fact, there seems to already be login info there for the other servers I've been connecting to in vim, although I have no memory of putting them there... it's been a long time since I tried to do this, I must have already figured out this issue long ago and forgotten all about how I did it. Whoops! Thanks for your answer.